# Variable scoping issue in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, while-loop, scope

I have this Bash snippet:

```
SourceFiles=()
grep --no-filename -R '^[a-zA-Z]' "$SourceDirectory/XilinxCoreLib/vhdl_analyze_order" | while read File; do
  SourceFiles+=("$SourceDirectory/XilinxCoreLib/$File")
done

echo $SourceFiles
```

It reads a file from disk and pipes all lines that start with an alphabetical character to the while loop.

My problem is that `$SourceFiles` is empty after processing the loop. I added an `echo $File` into the loop, which prints all lines from the file. So I assume a variable scoping problem.

What should I change here to get it working?

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: BTW, `while IFS= read -r File; do` will munge names less -- the original code will behave badly when you have filenames containing backslash literals or ending in whitespace. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) on using `while read` loops.

Comment: Also, if you want to print a whole array (not just its first element), use `printf '%s\n' "${SourceFiles[@]}"`, optionally using `%q\n` to quote filenames with nonprintable characters in `eval`-safe form.

Comment: The array is processed by a function. The echo is just for debugging :).

Comment: Sure, but if you use it to debug and see only one name when you expect to see 10 names, you might falsely assume that the `while read` code is still broken, when in fact the bug is with the `echo` command.

Comment: If you don't know correct array expansion syntax (and nothing in evidence in the question or prior comments indicates otherwise), you might have noticed *that* something was wrong, but how would you have noticed *what it was* (and distinguished between the `while read` and the `echo` as the source of your problem)? Which is to say: If someone doesn't demonstrate in a question that they grok an aspect of the subject matter at hand, commenting with a pointer is an innately helpful action. Scolding people for trying to be helpful is... not helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Each element of a pipeline is run in its own subshell, meaning its own execution environment; so to fix this, you'll need to move your `while`-loop out of a pipeline.

The simplest fix is to move the `grep` command into a process substitution; that is, change this structure:

```
grep ... | while ...
  ...
done
```

to this:

```
while ...
  ...
done < <(grep ...)
```

Comment: The space between both `<` signs is no typo?

Comment: @Paebbels, indeed, it is not a typo. `<()` is a process substitution construct that evaluates to the name of a file-like object, and the prior `<` is redirecting from the same. See [the bash-hackers wiki entry on process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).